# Link item inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have these tag : tag 1, tag 2, tag 3, tag 4...... (as much as i want)

I have these item : item A , item B , item C, item D, item E... (as much as i want)

Each item can have multi-tag. For example:

- Item A have tag 1, tag 2
- Item B have tag 1, tag 2, tag 3
- Item C have tag 2, tag 3, tag 4 , tag 5.......

What i want is a dictionary to access these item by tag

- myDictionary.tag(1).items to get the list item having tag 1
- myDictionary.tag(2).items to get the list item having tag 2
- myDictionary.tag(3).items to get the list item having tag 3

And when i want to edit the item C, so it will update on all tag.

I've try to using Dictionary(key, value) and add item to tag one per one. But it seem that if my item is heavy - so i'm wasting my memory when adding duplicate item to multi tag, and waste time when editing item by editing them on each tag. So i want to find a way to link item inside a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you show the real classes?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i don't have it, i want to have it.

Comment: You can query the dictionary using Linq and update the values of each Tag

Comment: Try the following dictionary: `Dictionary<String, List<String>> itemTags = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();` And what kind of items are these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wasting my memory when adding duplicate item to multi tag

As long as your item is a `class`, not a `struct`, adding it to multiple tags creates multiple references to the same object. There exists only one object, even though it's added to a dictionary several times.

> and I waste time when editing item by editing them on each tag

That's not going to happen either - if your object is a `class`, you need to edit a single object; the changes will be visible in all tags, because all tags have references to the same object.

You can use `Dictionary<string,List<MyObject>>` to store per-tag grouping of your objects. In addition, you could have a "master collection" of your objects - say, a list or a dictionary by some primary key. Adding the same object to multiple collections will not create duplicates - all collections would point to the same instance in memory.

The only issue that requires searching multiple collections comes up when you delete your object: you have to check all collections that may contain it, and delete the object from each one of them. This isn't a huge waste of time, though, because you do that only once in an object's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Item, List<Tag>> itemTags = new Dictionary<Item, List<Tag>>();
itemTags.Add(Item1, new List<Tag> { Tag1, Tag2 });
itemTags.Add(Item2, new List<Tag> { Tag1, Tag2 });
itemTags.Add(Item3, new List<Tag> { Tag3, Tag4 });
```

You could easliy iterate over this Dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Item, List<Tag>> item in itemTags)
{
    Item item = item.Key;
    List<Tag> tags = item.Value;
}
```

You can easily get the tags that belong to a Item now.
Could you specify of what Class Item and Tag are, so I could update my answer to correct datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

(1) it sounds like you're items can share tags, so a dictionary mapping tag to item wouldn't quite work. Instead, used a dictionary mapping tag to a collection of items

(2) as far as memory, if your item is value type (struct) then each instance in the dictionary will duplicate memory. Struct will also likely have the problem that updating one instance of the item won't propagate to updating all items in the dictionary. If Item is a class, then each instance will duplicate only the pointer (4-8 bytes, depending on whether you're running x64). This shouldn't be an issue unless you're collection is very, very large. Also, if it is a class then updating one instance of the item means that that update will show up even if you look up the item by a different tag.

I'd recommend going with a `Dictionary<Tag, List<Item>>`.

```
// add with
Item item = ...
foreach (var tag in tagsForItem) {
    List<Item> items;
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(tag, out items)) 
    {
       items = dictionary[tag] = new List<Item>();
    }
    items.Add(item)
}

// lookup with
var items = dictionary[tag];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a dictionary like the following:

```
Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>> dictionary = new DictionaryDictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>>();
```

Then add items to it with teh following way:

```
dictionary.Add("tag1",new List<string> { "itemA", "itemB" });
dictionary.Add("tag2",new List<string> { "itemA", "itemB", "itemC" });
dictionary.Add("tag3",new List<string> { "itemB", "itemC" });
```

When you want to edit an item, you could use the following method:

```
// item is the item you want to edit.
// tags are the tags that should be associated with this item.
// dictionary is the dictionary, in which you keep all these associations.
public void EditItem(string item, 
                     IEnumerable<string> tags, 
                     IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> dictionary)()
{
    // Get the tags in the given dictionary that associated with the given item.
    IEnumerable<string> tagsContainingItem = dictionary.Where(x=>x.Value.Contains(item))
                                                       .Select(x=x.Key);

    // Get the tags that shouldn't more associated with the item.
    IEnumerable<string> noCommonTags = tagsContainingItems.Except(tags);

    // Delete the item from the lists of the tags that should not be associated with the item.
    foreach(var tag in noCommonTags)
        dictionary[tag].Value.Remove(item);

    // Add the item to the new lists of the tags that are associated with the item.
    foreach(var tag in tags)
        dictionary[tag].Value.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple.

```
Dictionary<Item, List<Tag>> itemTagMap = new Dictionary<Item, List<Tag>>();

//Iterate through tags and update value for each tag
List<Tag> tags = itemTagMap[C];
for(int i=0; i < tags.Count; i++) { /* tags[i]. ... Update here */ } 

//Query all of the Items that have tagI
List<Item> results = itemTagMap.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(Tag_i)).ToList(); //Getting all the items that have Tag_i
```